# HERE-API: What is the unit of "SpeedLimit"

Tags: javascript, api

I saw the article about HERE API ( https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/spans-street-speed.html ), and I am currently trying to get speedLimit by using the API. It seems that this API works well in my environment, but I could not understand the unit of this speedLimit. Is the unit of speedLimit km/h or other? I would really appreciate it if you could answer my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"speedLimit":13.8888893 in this example of HERE routing API response:

```
                 {
                    "linkId":"-971369682",
                    "shape":[
                       "44.7477063,-79.8043458",
                       "44.7477063,-79.8043458"
                    ],
                    "speedLimit":13.8888893,
                    "_type":"PrivateTransportLinkType"
                 }
```

is in m/s that equals to 50 km/h. Another example is 16.6666679 m/s equals to 60 km/h.

Comment: This should be marked as right answer

Answer (score 0):

Speed limits units are dependent on the unit of distance.

Speed limits would be measured in kmh (km/hr) if your distance is measured in km.
And if the distance is measured in miles, it would measured mph (miles per hour)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In the case of the article ( https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/spans-street-speed.html), do you know whether it is kmh or mph?

Answer (score 0):

There is a short explanation here:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/here-map-content-schema/dev_guide/format-agnostic-data/format_agnostic_data_specification/topics/safety-camera-speed-limit-unit.html

your [link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/spans-street-speed.html) has example numbers like `13.8888893` for speed limit, which I don't understand either.

But there is also [Speed Limit Categories](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-speed-category.html)